# Is there a way to omit processing over a RDD partition with few elements in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD and I need to apply a computation on each partition (using `.mapPartition`) but only if the current partition of data have more than X elements.

Example: 
The number of elements in each partition of the RDD is:

> 80, 9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 60

I want to process only over the partitions with more than 50 elements.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be also done lazily without pre-calculating sizes. Filtering to partitions with at least two elements in this example

```
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

object DemoPartitioner extends Partitioner {
  override def numPartitions: Int = 3
  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
    case num: Int => num
  }
}

sc.parallelize(Seq((0, "a"), (0, "a"), (0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"), (2, "c")))
  .partitionBy(DemoPartitioner) // create 3 partitions of sizes 3,1,2
  .mapPartitions { it =>
    val firstElements = it.take(2).toSeq
    if (firstElements.size < 2) {
      Iterator.empty
    } else {
      firstElements.iterator ++ it
    }
  }.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(2,c)
(2,c)
(0,a)
(0,a)
(0,a)
```

So partition 1 with just a single element was skipped

Comment: Thanks, it works!. But I don't understand why this line `firstElements.iterator ++ it`

Comment: It's because `take(2)` already consumes two first elements from the iterator. So combining the elements that are in `firstElements` and then what is left of the iterator to get the original elements

Comment: And also, what would happen if one partition doesn't have elements?

Comment: Nothing special, it would be ignored as expected. You can test that bu changing to `override def numPartitions: Int = 4`